# Python: Get all the non-overlapping, consecutive sublists from a list

Tags: python, list, iteration, sublist

I'm trying to figure out an elegant/efficient solution for finding sublists in a list, with certain constraints.

For example, given this list:

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

And a value for maxLength:

```
maxLength = 4
```

Find all sublists in the values list such that:

- Sublist length is between 1 and maxLength
- Sublists are consecutive
- Sublists are non-overlapping

So in this example, these are acceptable solutions:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f']]
...
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']]
...
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
...
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

These are not acceptable:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['d', 'e'], ['f']]           #Error: not consecutive, 'c' is missing
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']] #Error: overlapping, 'c' is in two subsets
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']]        #Error: the first sublist has length > maxLength (4)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong?

Comment: My solution involved 3 for loops and seemed terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
maxLength = 4

def groupings(d):
  if not d:
    yield []
  else:
    for i in range(1, maxLength+1):
      for c in groupings(d[i:]):
         yield [d[:i], *c]

_d = list(groupings(values))
new_d = [a for i, a in enumerate(_d) if a not in _d[:i]]
```

Output:

```
[[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']], [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f']], [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f']], [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f']], [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f']], [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']], [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f']], [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f']], [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f']], [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f']], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f']], [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]]
```

Comment: This is a great solution, just one small tweak.  Line 8 should be changed to "for i in range(1, maxLength+1)".  That way, the result includes those sublists of length 4.  Your current solution doesn't have any of length 4.

Comment: @Mose Oh, it is between 1 and maxLength, inclusive? Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.